# Entity Control Boundary and CEC Patterns

Tags: java, controls, entity, boundary

i have reading this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-jan/o11java-195110.html

which mentioned about Entity Control Boundary and CEC patterns.

AFAIK, the boundary is a facade pattern where CDI is better than ejb in some situation but ejb is enough for other situation.

I have read it and not fully understand it.

I understand that the entity bean(POJO) using JPA is model, view is jsf/jsp , controller is servlet.

Do the implementation of request (action) or component base mvc affected this design pattern ?

Therefore, anyone kind enough to explain the purpose/functionality of each class with class and sequence diagram?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An entity class manages persistent data, for example a database.

A boundary class provides an interface to a user or an external system.  For example, it might display a dialog requesting information from a user.

A control class encapsulates the main logic for a use case or part of a use case.

A boundary object could spawn a control object, e.g. to process information that a user has just entered.  Or a control object could spawn a boundary object, perhaps to request information.  But to ease reuse an entity object should not spawn boundary or control objects.